# NSURLConnection problem?

Tags: iphone

HI,
i am using sample code from to handle Multiple NSUrlCOnnection from the link [multiple url connection](http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/15/multiple-async-nsurlconnections-example/)

when i use CustomURLConnection as NSObject inwhich i specified one Method as to enable

```
CustomURLConnection *connection = [[CustomURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES tag:tag];
```

through the following

```
 - (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate   startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately tag:(NSString *)_tag

 {
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:startImmediately];
self.tag = _tag;
return self;
  }
```

it gives error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate   startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately tag:(NSString *)_tag
 {
    if(self = [super initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate])
    {   
       self.tag = _tag;
    }
    return self;
  }
```

(If I got you right and CustomURLConnection extends NSURLConnection and the code you pasted is CustomURLConnection's init code.)

Comment: senthilmuthu, see the original implementation here: http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/02/custom-nsurlconnection-class-with-tag/

Comment: It appears that in his case CustomURLConnection inherits from NSObject and not NSURLConnection.

Comment: Yes, missed this in his description. So I think your answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `self`. If `CustomURLConnection` inherits from `NSObject`the method should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate   startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately tag:(NSString *)_tag {
      if(self = [super init]) {
         self.connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:startImmediately] autorelease];
         self.tag = _tag;
      }
      return self;
 }
```

You should also make sure that `connection` is an iVar of that Class and gets properly released in `dealloc`. Same for `tag`make sure to add

```
 @synthesize tag,connection;
```

after `@implementation` and to declare a tag iVar and property.

Comment: I have edited the code. Make sure to synthesize both: tag and connection.